# C++ implementation of merge sort

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I am studying the merge sort algorithm and implemented it. In the `mergeSort` function, I am allocating two new vectors. Can I do it without allocating extra memory? Are there any other suggestions?

```
#ifndef MERGE_SORT
#define MERGE_SORT
#include <vector>


template<typename T>
void merge(std::vector<T>& array, std::vector<T> left, std::vector<T> right) {
    array.clear();
    auto lsize = left.size();
    auto rsize = right.size();
    unsigned int i=0, j=0;
    while (i < lsize && j < rsize) {
        if (left[i] < right[j]) {
            array.push_back(left[i]);
            ++i;
        }else {
            array.push_back(right[j]);
            ++j;
        }
    }
    for(; i<lsize; ++i)
        array.push_back(left[i]);
    for(; j<rsize; ++j)
        array.push_back(right[j]);
}


template<typename T>
void mergeSort(std::vector<T>& seq) {
    auto n = seq.size();
    if (n > 1) {
        auto start = seq.begin();
        auto end = seq.end();
        auto middle = start + n / 2;
        std::vector<T> left(start, middle);
        std::vector<T> right(middle, end);
        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        merge(seq, left, right);
    }
}


#endif // MERGE_SORT
```

Answer (score 5):

- > Can I do it without allocating extra memory?

  In fact, yes.  The trick is to merge recursively (technically, the \$O(\log N)\$ extra memory is still necessary for recursion). Here is a pseudo-code for the classic in-place merge:

  ```
  // Prerequisite: [begin, mid) and [mid, end) ranges are sorted
  inplace_merge(begin, mid, end)
  {
      if (end - begin) < 2) return;

      left = begin + (mid - begin)/2;
      right = lower_bound(mid, end, *left);

      mid = rotate(left, mid, right);

      inplace_merge(begin, left, mid);
      inplace_merge(mid, right, end);
  }
  ```
- **Stability**

  The most important feature of merge sort is stability: the elements compared equal retain their original order (not very important for integers, but immensely important when sorting structured data). Your implementation loses it:

  ```
  if (left[i] < right[j]) {
      array.push_back(left[i]);
      ++i;
  }else {
      array.push_back(right[j]);
      ++j;
  }
  ```

  In case of equality it is an element from `right` to be pushed first. Easy to fix with

  ```
  if (right[j] < left[i])
  ```

  or

  ```
  if (left[i] <= right[j])
  ```

  First way is preferred, because it doesn't assume existence of `operator<=`.

Comment: Forgot totally about stability. +1

Answer (score 2):

> Can I do it without allocating extra memory?

Probably not.
But you can do it without allocating as much memory.

Here:

```
    std::vector<T> left(start, middle);
    std::vector<T> right(middle, end);
    mergeSort(left);
```

So you have just allocated as much space as the original. So we are at `2n`. But then you make a recursive call. Which will do exactly the same thing (but with half the array). So we are at `2.5n` then you will recursively call it again. Eventually you will allocate a total of `3n` space (plus control structures).

An easy way to get around this is to make your interface allocate the scratch array then call your internal merge sort passing the original and a scratch area. So the total amount of space you will use is `2n` (and only one extra control structure).

```
template<typename T>
void mergeSort(std::vector<T>& seq) {

    std::vector<T>  scratch(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq));
    mergeSortWithScratch(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq),
                         std::begin(scratch), std::end(scratch));
}


template<typename I>
void mergeSortWithScratch(I beginData, I endData, I beginScratch, I endScratch) {
    auto n = std::distance(beginData, endData);
    if (n > 1) {
        auto middleData     = beginData;     std::advance(middleData,   n/2);
        auto middelScratch  = beginScratch;  std::advance(beginScratch, n/2);

        mergeSort(beginData, middelData, beginScratch, middelScratch);
        mergeSort(middelData, endData, middelScratch, endScratch);
        merge(beginScratch, middleScratch, endScratch, beginData);
    }
}
```

Slightly simpler way of writing:

```
    if (left[i] < right[j]) {
        array.push_back(left[i]);
        ++i;
    }else {
        array.push_back(right[j]);
        ++j;
    }
```

Use the trinary expression.

```
   array.push_back(left[i] < right[j]
                         ? left[i++]
                         : right[j++]);
```

The next thing to look at (if you have C++1) is move semantics. These are generally at least as fast as copy but can be a lot quicker for non POD types.

```
    array.emplace_back(std::move(left[i] < right[j]
                                  ? left[i++]
                                  : right[j++]));
```

Comment: thanks for the info.
Why you use auto middle = begin;std::advance(middle, n/2) ?
Is there any benefit using the std::advance?
Also instead vector.begin() / end() why u use std::begin / end ?.
Thanks

Comment: Because all standard algorithms are based on iterators. So I am used to writing my code in terms of iterators. Thus `std::begin()` and `std::end()` can also be applied to arrays (or other containers). Thus it allows my code to be container agnostic (when this is useful) at no extra cost. With a slight tweak the above would work for arrays and vectors and C-Arrays or any container that supported random access iterators.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have implemented this (recursively), it's hard to avoid the vector allocations. Indeed, this can be expensive, as you're potentially doing **`O(logn)`** vector allocations. What you can try instead is replacing the vector with a hand-written linked list. There's also an in-place merge sort algorithm that you can realize by carefully swapping elements, and maintaining only 1 extra buffer vector.

**There are other implicit vector copies** that you can avoid though:

```
void merge(std::vector<T>& array, 
           std::vector<T> left, 
           std::vector<T> right);
```

You should replace this with the following to prevent copying `left` and `right` on every function call.

```
void merge(std::vector<T>& array, 
           const std::vector<T>& left, 
           const std::vector<T>& right);
```